# Symfony project unable to load in localhost

Tags: php, symfony

I am new in symfony framework. Getting the below error when download the full project in localhost but it works in server.

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry' not found
>   in D:\wamp\www\DOFE\edin\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Registry.php
>   on line 28

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install composer ?

Comment: yes I did. Why?

Comment: Probably your composer install failed at some point. Try removing the vendor folder and running `composer install` again.

Comment: I have install the composer and now I am getting the below error.       

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to execute `composer dump-autoload` to force composer to regenerate the autoload namespaces for your app.

Regarding your comment, if you are getting this message it means you are in prod and you should switch to the dev environment to have details about the error (access to the symfony profiler).

Just add app_dev.php after the host in the url.